# Vagrant: Is it possible to use Vagrant with VMWare as a provider without paying?

Tags: virtualbox, vmware, macintosh, vagrant

I am learning Vagrant from scratch from a Udemy tutorial. I want to use my centos machine to install everything and run all from there, but they use VirtualBox and in my Centos machine (a dell computer), I was unable to make VB work, it seems it is a problem with the BIOS and secure boot. I just wasn't able to deactivate it. So I was trying to use VMWare Workstation 14 player as a provider for Vagrant. But when I am trying to check the setup it says that:

"A valid license is required to run the vagrant vmware provider. Please visit URL to purchase a license. Once you purchase a license, you can install it..."

I am using Workstation player, because it says it is free, And actually VMWare has a lot of different programs that I am not sure what do I need. Which brings me to the question:
Is it possible to use Vagrant with VMWare as a provider without paying? If so, how can I do that?

If there are no other way, I might use my mac to continue with this.

Regards

Comment: Why would the BIOS effect the booting of a virtual Box machine within the operating system?

Comment: This seems to be a legal (licencing) question, so off topic. However VM is propitiatory, you are probably in licence infringement, if you do. I am also wondering what problem will stop Vbox from working, but allow VMWare.

Comment: @RamanSailopal and ctrl-alt-delor the issue is with vboxdrv, it said that it was a kernel issue, it seems that the kernel failed to load some modules at boot, ive been doing some research and it is because since windows 8-10 computers comes with secure boot and this prevents vboxdrv from work. I tried to dissable it and use the legacy version of the bios, but as soon as I restart the system goes into recovery mode and thats it. It doesnt load at all

Comment: I run Windows 8 with Vagrant and Oracle Virtual Box fine.

Comment: Hi @RamanSailopal I dont have Windows on that machine, I only have centos, maybe if I had windows I wont be having that issue. The problem is with: centos, linux kernel, ans secure boot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  There is no way to legally or ethically use the Vagrant VMware provider without a paid license.

Comment: I guess Ill have to work on my Mac instead, thanks Tim

Comment: You're welcome.  Or pony up $79 for a license.  10% off if you're a verifiable student.

Comment: haha..... man... Im jobless at the momment, even if I had them. I would probably spend those 79 on god of war

Comment: then Mac it is! :)